# ItextSharp HTML to PDF conversion how to convert text with superscript and subscript as it is

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, itext

Hi this is my implementation to convert an HTML in to PDF as i

```
            private static PdfContent PdfContentA()
                    {
                        var cssText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\kalanamithm\Desktop\Ground Operations\MvcApplication1\MvcApplication1\Resources\CSS\FTL.css");
                        //var htmlText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\kalanamithm\Desktop\Ground Operations\MvcApplication1\MvcApplication1\Resources\HTML\grace.html");

                        var htmlText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\kalanamithm\Desktop\Ground Operations\MvcApplication1\MvcApplication1\Resources\HTML\FLT.html");

                        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                        var document = new Document();
                        var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream);
                        document.Open();

                        var xmlWorkerFontProvider = new XMLWorkerFontProvider();
                        xmlWorkerFontProvider.Register("http://localhost:58045/Resources/Fonts/TequilaSunset-Regular.ttf");
                        xmlWorkerFontProvider.Register("http://localhost:58045/Resources/Fonts/Mf Sippin On Sunshine.ttf");
                        using (var cssMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cssText)))
                        {
                            using (var htmlMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(htmlText)))
                            {
                                XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, document, htmlMemoryStream, cssMemoryStream);
                            }
                        }


                        document.Close();
                        var pdfContent = new PdfContent
                        {
                            MemoryStream = memoryStream,
                            FileName = "SomeName"
                        };
                        return pdfContent;
                    }
```

um facing a problem here , when um converting SuperScript pr subscript it wont show in Pdf.

Is there a solution  for this in ITextSharp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution 
in the html I manually created a superscript as follows and it works
(based on my scenario)

```
 "<span style=\"width:500px;\">" +
                            "<span>500 m</span>" +
                            "<span style=\"vertical-align:super;font-size:8px;\">2</span>" +
                        "</span>" +
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your question mentions 'as it is' then you can add the css for sub and sup tags in you css file. And then all subscript and superscript tags will render fine in pdf. No need to change the intial html.

```
<style>
sup {
vertical-align: super;
font-size: 9px;
}

sub {
vertical-align: sub;
font-size: 9px;
}
</style>
```